# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections (I)V

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, gradle, glassfish, payara

Я пытаюсь запустить `Spring Boot`-приложение на сервере `Glassfish` (`Payara 5`).

При попытке запустить приложение возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот текст ошибки:

```
[2020-09-26 04:06:43,506] Artifact Gradle : library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

[2020-09-26 04:06:50,605] Artifact Gradle : library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

[2020-09-26 04:06:50,606] Artifact Gradle : library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (exploded): java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections (I)V. Please see server.log for more details**.
```

Далее смотрю файл `server.log`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть тут ошибка:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections (I)V

Пробовал найти информацию в интернете. В интернете я нашёл информацию, что надо заменить старую версию библиотеки `org.yaml.snakeyaml` на более новую (`1.19`).
У меня в данный момент версия `1.26`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал разные версии, но это не помогло.

**Можете подсказать, в чём ещё может быть проблема?**

Файл `build.gradle` такой:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' // плагин для правильной загрузки зависимостей Spring

war {
    archiveBaseName = 'library'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    // Репозиторий для скачивания зависимостей primefaces
    maven {
        url 'http://repository.primefaces.org'
    }
}

ext['hibernate.version'] = '5.4.2.Final'

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat' // исключаю Tomcat так как использую GlassFish (Payara)
}

dependencies {
    // Для стартеров будет использоваться версия, указанная в переменной springBootVersion
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") // для использования Spring MVC
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") // для работы с Hibernate
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security") // аутентификация, авторизация
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop") // для использования аспектов
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") // служебные данные во время работы приложения (бины, endpoints и пр.)
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:+'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.12' // драйвер для соединения с БД
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0' // в GlassFish (Payara) уже есть эта библиотека, поэтому добавляю только для компиляции

    providedCompile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6' // уменьшение кода
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'

//    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.26' // по умолчанию версия 1.26

    // Frontend
    implementation 'org.primefaces:primefaces:6.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.omnifaces:omnifaces:2.5.1'
    implementation 'net.bootsfaces:bootsfaces:1.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:+' // для загрузки файлов в приложении
    implementation 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:+'
    implementation('org.primefaces.themes:bootstrap:1.0.10')
}
```

Файл `ServletInitializer.java`:

```
package ru.my_projects.online_library;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Текущая структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня такая ошибка. Тебе удалось как-то решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо обновить библиотеку snakeyaml на версию 1.23 или выше. Это в будет выглядет примерно так:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.23</version>
</dependency>
```

а в гредл:

```
implementation "org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.23"
```

для подробности можете посмотреть на эту [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533309/3436941)